# Error in print(iris_ctree) : object 'iris_ctree' not found

Tags: r

I am making use of `party` package to generate decision tree for Iris data set using R.

I have implemented following piece of code using the tutorial from

http://www.rdatamining.com/examples/decision-tree

```
library("party")
str(iris)
iris_ctree <- ctree(Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data=iris)
print(iris_ctree)
```

I am getting the following error when I run the code:

```
Error in print(iris_ctree) : object 'iris_ctree' not found
```

When I made a search for this I found that such errors are thrown when a variable that has not been defined is used somewhere in the code. But I am getting this error even if `iris_ctree` has been defined.

I am completely new to this world of R. Can anyone point out the mistake? It must be very silly mistake.

Comment: Close and reopen your R session and make sure that when you re-run the code you haven't got any previous errors. Also, you don't need `print`. As of now, this isn't reproducible.

Comment: Your code works well for me. Make sure you have the `iris` data set loaded using `data(iris)`.

Comment: I am getting strange results. I am using R Studio. Each time I run I am getting different errors. I am using the run button to run the script. Depending on the line on which I place the cursor before running, I get a different result which pertains to the line on which I place the cursor